# how to create a select in vue's createElement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component that uses template, I'd like to change it to use render function, I know createElement('h1', 'title'), but how to use it with something like 'select' with all the options? here is the template based component:

https://jsfiddle.net/aaoehLqe/

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <myselect  v-bind:option= "option" ></myselect>
  {{option}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the select component with `createElement`:

```
Vue.component('myselect', {
  props: ['option'],
  render: function(createElement) {
    var self = this
    return createElement(
      'select', {
        domProps: {
          value: self.option.value
        },
        on: {
          input: function(event) {
            self.option.value = event.target.value
          }
        }
      }, [
        createElement('option', {
          attrs: {
            value: 0
          }
        }, 'Under 1'),
        createElement('option', {
          attrs: {
            value: 1
          }
        }, '1'),
      ]
    )
  },
})
```

You can see the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aaoehLqe/1/

To understand how it works, you can see the API details of [createElement](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments) in docs:

```
// @returns {VNode}
createElement(
  // {String | Object | Function}
  // An HTML tag name, component options, or function
  // returning one of these. Required.
  'div',
  // {Object}
  // A data object corresponding to the attributes
  // you would use in a template. Optional.
  {
    // (see details in the next section below)
  },
  // {String | Array}
  // Children VNodes. Optional.
  [
    createElement('h1', 'hello world'),
    createElement(MyComponent, {
      props: {
        someProp: 'foo'
      }
    }),
    'bar'
  ]
)
```

Comment: domProps, props and attrs, what are the difference? a little confusing here, please enlighten, thanks

Comment: @AngeloC props are for parent child communication, [domProps](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ae93d2bef8e20402ae3501aa5cdcf14b0ee19c12/src/platforms/web/server/modules/dom-props.js) are used to pass DOM properties such as `textContent `, `innerHTML `, `acceptCharset `, etc, while [attrs](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ae93d2bef8e20402ae3501aa5cdcf14b0ee19c12/src/platforms/web/server/modules/attrs.js#L29) are used for normal HTML attributes such as id, `name ` and  similar [others](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ae93d2bef8e20402ae3501aa5cdcf14b0ee19c12/src/platforms/web/util/attrs.js).

Comment: @Saurabh So you know domProps/attr is because you have read the source code of vue? or if there is a vue document about domProps?  I have search domProps/createElement from vue doc and found nothing.

Comment: @hyyou2010 https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html?#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic version based off your fiddle.

```
Vue.component("mySelect", {
  props:["value"],
  render(h){
    const vm = this;
    let options = [];
    for (let c = 0; c < 18; c++)
      options.push(h("option", {
        domProps:{innerHTML: c},
        attrs:{value: c},
      }))
    return h("select",{
      domProps:{
        value: this.value.value
      },
      on:{
        input(event){
          vm.$emit('input', {value:event.target.value})
        }
      }
    }, options)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
Vue.component('myselect', {
  props: ['option'],
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        //
      ]
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    var self = this

    return h('select', {
      class: { 'form-control': true },
      domProps: { value: this.option.value },
      on: {
        input (event) {
          self.option.value = event.target.value
        }
      }
    }, this.items.map((item) => h('option', {
      attrs: { value: item }
    }, item)))
  }
})
```

[ [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/8eu2kweh/) ]

Please check the [`v-if and v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-if-and-v-for) & [`v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model) sections.